# Display TextField text into TableView cell

Tags: javafx-8

I want to display whatever I type in a textfield into a a single column tableview.

```
ObservableList<String> obType = FXCollections.observableArrayList();

TextField typeText = new TextField();

TableView<String> tableMainType = new TableView<String>();
TableColumn<String, String> mainType = new TableColumn<String, String("Type");
?????????????????????????????

btnMainAdd.setOnAction(e -> {
    obType.add(typeText.getText());
    tableMainType.setItems(obType);
});
```

Can you help please?
Thanks,

Marco

Comment: What are you missing? Just how to set the `cellValueFactory`?

Comment: I think @James_D gave you a perfect hint - have a look at the TableView JavaDoc (https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/TableView.html).

Comment: @Marco So can you update your question? It has nothing at all to do with the text field, right? It's just about displaying a single column of strings in a table view. (You'll probably find this is already answered if you search - is there a reason you're using a `TableView` instead of a `ListView` for this?)

Comment: I didn't know how to set the cellValueFactory when adding only a string and not an object parameter. I couldn't find a solution anywhere to this problem so I used a ListView instead and it's working. But if any of you knows the answer, please let me know. Thanks